# How to draw a density heat map on Ternary plot in R?

Tags: r, ternary

Heads up I am an R noob so bare with please!

I am trying to identify areas where the most data points are situated using a density heatmap.

[Here is what the plot looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UKA5.jpg)

What will I have to add to this code I've done so far (I listed less data points obviously) to apply this 'heatmap'?

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2), mar=rep(0.3, 4))
TernaryPlot(atip = "Red", btip = "Green", ctip = "Blue", alab="Redder\u2192", blab="Greener \u2192", clab="Bluer \u2190",
            point='Up', lab.cex=0.8, grid.minor.lines = 0,
            grid.lty='solid', col=rgb(0.9,0.9,0.9), grid.col='White', 
            axis.col=rgb(0, 0, 0), ticks.col=rgb(0, 0, 0),
            padding=0.08)
data_points <- list(
  c(0.89,0.88,0.78),
  c(0.98,0.96,0.92),
  c(0.6,0.52,0.28),
  c(0.88,0.9,0.85),
  c(0.96,0.87,0.6),
  c(0.63,0.53,0.29),
  c(0.92,0.85,0.09),
  c(0.84,0.87,0.87),
  c(0.93,0.88,0.88),
  c(0.98,0.76,0.71)
)
AddToTernary(points, data_points, bg=vapply(data_points, function (x) rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3], 1, maxColorValue=1), character(1)), pch=25, cex=0.8)
AddToTernary(text, data_points, names(data_points), cex=0.8, font=2)
```

Sorry for being so silly, very new to all this, learning lots thanks to this website!

Answer (score 0):

The `TernaryPlot` function from the `Ternary` package creates and styles a blank Ternary plot. If you would like to show your data points, you need to use the `TernaryPoints` function:

```
TernaryPlot(atip = "Red", btip = "Green", ctip = "Blue", alab="Redder\u2192", blab="Greener \u2192", clab="Bluer \u2190",
        point='Up', lab.cex=0.8, grid.minor.lines = 0,
        grid.lty='solid', col=rgb(0.9,0.9,0.9), grid.col='White', 
        axis.col=rgb(0, 0, 0), ticks.col=rgb(0, 0, 0),
        padding=0.08)

TernaryPoints(data_points)
```

You will get the following plot:

[image: ternary plot with ternery library]

Another option is to use the `vcd` library:

```
library(vcd)

# convert data points into a matrix
data_points = matrix(unlist(data_points), ncol=3, byrow=T)
ternaryplot(x=data_points)
```

Using `vcd`, you should get the following plot:

[image: ternery plot with vcd]